# Python: WhatsApp Cloud API webhook

Tags: python, api, server, webhooks, whatsapp

I have a WhatsApp business account with a number linked to it. I want some way to receive messages using python from it. I couldn't find a solution that doesn't require online hosting(heroku, glitch, twilio ect.).

Comment: So how do you even know it's possible? Or do you even know? Or are you asking if it's possible? Either way, none of those are on-topic questions for this site in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp cloud API will request you a webhook to post the messages received on the number you linked to the business account.

You can expose a webhook listener selfhosted without the need to use a hosting provider. For obvious reasons, you should consider hosting it when you move your development into production.

I would recommend using ngrok or a cloudflare tunnel (both are free) during development.

Here's an example of each, the use-case is testing a webhook:

NGROK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FHbfo-wRtY

Cloudflare tunnels: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMyoH4-mOiA

Answer (score 0):

or use glitch.me cause ngrok webhooks is banned by facebook

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).